# Битовый сдвиг влево

Tags: java, битовые-операции

Почему переменная val будет инициализирована значение 1, а не значением 0?

```
int val = 1 << 32;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Согласно документации ([JLS 15.19](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.19)):

> If the promoted type of the left-hand operand is int, only the five lowest-order bits of the right-hand operand are used as the shift distance. It is as if the right-hand operand were subjected to a bitwise logical AND operator & (§15.22.1) with the mask value 0x1f (0b11111). The shift distance actually used is therefore always in the range 0 to 31, inclusive.

то есть

> Если тип левой части после numeric promotion — `int` [это как раз наш случай], то лишь пять младших бит из правой части будут использованы в качестве размера сдвига. Эффект такой же, как если бы правую часть подвергли операции `&` с маской 0x1f (0b11111). Таким образом, расстояние сдвига всегда находится в промежутке от 0 до 31, включительно.

Это означает, что сдвиг на 32 бита работает как сдвиг на 0, на 33 как на 1 и т. д.

Comment: Эх, опередили. А я хотел пример еще дописать))  как `1 << 32  === 32 & 0x1F === 0`, т.к. `0x1F` = 31 ....... то есть получается смещение на ноль.....ни стыда ни совести)))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский: Сорри :) Интересно, как оно в C#...

Comment: да вроде также ....там есть пример, правда с байтами https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/8xftzc7e(v=vs.100).aspx#Anchor_2    но суть вроде та же

Comment: А все от того, что в IA-32 такие инструкции, с аргументом пятибитовым.

Comment: Ага, так и есть: http://ideone.com/7OXlX4

Comment: У C# для них основной таргет — интеловская архитектура. А вот Java что ж так?