# JS. Неожиданное поведение при побитовом сдвиге влево (<<)

Tags: javascript, битовые-операции

```
var a = 0b00000000000000000000000000000001 // 1
var b = a << 31 // -2147483648 (Логично, мы сдвинули биты на 31 влево)
var c = b << 1 // 0 (Тоже логично, единица вышла за пределы 32-х битного числа)
var d = a << 32 // 1
```

Ожидалось, что последняя строчка приравняет **d = 0**, ведь инструкция гласит:
["a<<b Сдвигает двоичное представление a на b битов влево, добавляя справа нули"](https://learn.javascript.ru/bitwise-operators).

```
> 1 << 32
1
> (1 << 31) << 1
0
```

***Чем это вызвано и как этого избежать?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласно [спецификации](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-numeric-types-number-leftShift), при сдвиге влево (`x << y`), для чисел

1. первый операнд приводится к Int32
2. второй операнд приводится к UInt32
3. от второго операнда берутся последние 5 бит (`y & 0x1F`)
4. на полученный результат и происходит сдвиг

---

Возвращаясь к примеру в вопросе:

```
a << 32
```

`32`<sub>10</sub>=`100000`<sub>2</sub>

Последние 5 бит от 32 - 0

Таким образом происходит сдвиг на 0 бит - как результат: значение `a` как было 1, так и осталось.

Answer (score 0):

[Ответ на тот же вопрос в Java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/541488/%D0%91%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B3-%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE?rq=1) натолкнул меня на мысль, что если правая часть "<<" превышает 31, то от нее берется остаток от деления на 32, который и является итоговым сдвигом.
Поэтому

```
(1<<32) == (1<<0); // Это истина
```

Избежать этого можно, если добавить проверку

```
if(b < 32) d = a << b; else d = 0;
```